# Android to Slack sharing issue

Tags: android, android-intent, slack, slack-api

I found an issue with sharing text messages to slack, here the simple code:

```
String content = "500 wert wert wert wert wert wert ewrt wert ewr tiwert uiweryt weuryt werytuiweyrt yweuritiuwertywerui twerytu weuirty uwerytuweurityuiwer tuiwery tuiweryt uiwerytui weryt iwerytiuweyrtuiweyrt weuyrtui werytui ewryti weryt uiweyrt ewrt uiewryt uiweryt uiewryt iuewryt iuert wueiryti werutiu weryt yuwiert wert wert wert wert wert werthwer tiwerituiwer tuiewrutywueirt wurtuiwret yweruit uiwery tuiwyertiu weyrut iuwerytui weruit wert wert r wert wert wert wert wert ewryety wert ret ret er tetewqwert" ;
final Intent sendIntent = new Intent();
sendIntent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
sendIntent.setType("text/plain");
sendIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, content);
sendIntent.setPackage("com.Slack");
startActivityForResult(sendIntent, 1092);
```

and if `content` contains `< 500` characters, this code works ok, but if there is `>= 500` characters it places to the 'Title':
[image]

is there way to fix it?

Comment: If this screenshot is referring to the Slack app on Android its looks more like a bug and I would suggest to open a ticket withe the Slack Team.

Comment: thank you, i've sent feedback to slack. looking for workarounds.

Comment: I think the bug is still there 

Comment: yeah, and still no feedback from slack :(

Comment: @Siarhei is there a bug report I can upvote somewhere?

Comment: seems no, but it would be nice if you report about the issue as well. thank you

Comment: @Siarhei Just reported it, let's see